# Arranging Images in circular way using html

Tags: html

I want to arrange images in a circular way when designing a website. For that using CSS we can do it easily.
But I want to arrange those images using HTML only.
Can someone explain if it is possible with the code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: CSS is used for styling elements. HTML is only the markup. What you're asking does not make any sense.

Comment: @SouravGhosh  this is my first question. I just had a doubt and wanna clarify that and so I just asked besides How to Ask format.

Comment: @J.Titus yeah but I was asked to do that. That is a question asked in the interview.

Comment: Infosys interview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to arrange those images using HTML only

You cannot spatially arrange *anything* using HTML only.

Even when the browser gives an HTML element a spatial arrangement - that's just a default set of CSS rules being deployed by the browser... prior to your writing your own CSS rules to declare how that element should be spatially arranged.

HTML only describes the **structure** of the document.

Visually, HTML is entirely agnostic.

Comment: Thank you for answering. 